# Eclipse code formatting behaving differently for one project

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

I am using eclipse oxygen version.

I am facing a strange issue in code formatting java projects in eclipse.
I have a custom .epf file for the code formatting and code styling.

I have multiple java projects and styling works perfectly fine for all projects except one.

In that project whenever I try to do code format it’s doing a different format styling than other projects.   This drive me crazy.

Can someone please throw some light in finding why only one project styling is different?

Comment: Easier just to recreate the project

Comment: did you Checked "Enable Project specific settings"  ?

Comment: I did not know that there was an option to do the project specific settings. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the project Properties at the 'Java Code Style > Formatter' page.

Is the 'Enable project specific settings' option set? Is the Active Profile different from the main preferences?

Comment: Yes. I can see a different project specific settings. Thanks. It solved the problem. What I am wondering is , I  deleted all the projects and reimported it, still it was there. Therefore it was not something I personally did.  I will look into the conf file to see whether I can find the project specific settings enable/disable keyword